# Kill systemd oneshot service after timeout

Tags: systemd

Is it possible to kill a oneshot service after a timeout?

Suppose a service is triggered periodically by a timer. The service typically takes 3 seconds to finish. However, your service is also buggy and once in a while it will run in an infinite loop. Fixing the service is out of your scope. Thus what you want is to kill the service after a timeout.

We can simulate the *buggy* service as follows:

```
[Unit]

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'while true; do echo x; sleep 1; done'

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Reading the manpage I could only find option `TimeoutStopSec` which sounds promising. Adding

```
TimeoutStopSec=10s
```

to the `[Service]` section, however, does not kill the service at all---even after several minutes.

Comment: `TimeoutStopSec` is for killing the process after a timeout when the service is stopping. Your service isn't being stopped, and you don't have any `ExecStop`, so that's not applicable here. `TimeoutStartSec` applies to `ExecStart`.

Comment: Thanks @muru. I somehow got confused by the manpage about the extra statement that whenever `type=oneshot` that the `TimeoutStartSec` is disabled then. However, as you pointed out, you can just set it manually. Now it works. Thanks again! If you want to come up with an answer, I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The man page `systemd.service` says:

> TimeoutStartSec=
> Configures the time to wait for start-up. If a daemon service does
> not signal start-up completion within the configured time, the
> service will be considered failed and will be shut down again.
> Takes a unit-less value in seconds, or a time span value such as
> "5min 20s". Pass "infinity" to disable the timeout logic. Defaults
> to DefaultTimeoutStartSec= from the manager configuration file,
> except when Type=oneshot is used, in which case the timeout is
> disabled by default (see systemd-system.conf(5)).

I got confused by the last sentence which does not mean, that you cannot re-enable `TimeoutStartSec`. Thus the solution is as simple as adding `TimeoutStartSec=10s`

Comment: Your not the only one who misread that sentence. SystemD's documentation should be rewritten for clarity.